# Use multiple certificates for same server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-ecs, white-labelling

I am creating a web application which will be sold to customers as white label, meaning the customers will see their domain in the URL but all the traffic will be routed through my servers.

I am using AWS as a host. For each new customer I create a cloudfront distribution but the problem is with the ECS backend, I don't want to create a new cluster for each customer but having the web client and server on different domains gives me a ton of problems.
The server uses an SSL certificate so I can't create a route in the customer's domain to point to my server.

Anyone has any idea how I can efficiently create multiple endpoints, each with his own certificate without having to set-up extra instances and ECS clusters?

Comment: AWS load balancers support multiple SSL certificates. So you could load many of them on one balancer, one for each customer (don't know maximum number).

Comment: @Marcin Worked perfectly, post it as an answer

Comment: Thank you. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application Load balancer [supports](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/) using multiple TLS/SSL certificates on  using **Server Name Indication** (SNI), which allows you to:

> host multiple TLS secured applications, each with its own TLS certificate, behind a single load balancer. In order to use SNI, all you need to do is **bind multiple certificates** to the same secure listener on your load balancer. ALB will **automatically choose** the optimal TLS certificate for each client. These new features are provided at no additional charge.